# Possibilities after stage IV melanoma diagnosis

Tags: cancer, practice-of-medicine, hospital, melanoma

My aunt is 62 and was diagnosed last november with stage IV metastatic melanoma. She had an operation to get a tumor removed and is undergoing an  immunotherapy treatment that I believe is experimental. So far it's caused some severe complications (typhlitis) and doesn't seem like it is going to work.

My question is not so much medical but about doctors and medical departments. I'm not sure how to proceed, and un particular if it makes sense to search for opinions in other places besides the oncology department in the hospital in my city (Valencia) in Spain where she is being treated. Basically I don't know how and if doctors share and have access to ongoing clinical studies and new treatments. I don't know if looking for others opinions migh mean stumbling some promising possibility that doctors treating her right now might not be aware of.

Comment: We can't answer any questions about your aunt or any other individual here. It's possible if you made a more general question about access to clinical trial information it would be considered on-topic, though it doesn't quite fit the [scope](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but if your aunt is still alive and well 9 months after a stage IV diagnosis, she's doing very well. I suspect her treatment is in fact working. The presence of complications is also a good sign; people who have more side effects seem to do better. Now, all the immunotherapies for melanoma are new and experimental; it's possible some doctors will know things that others won't, or that coming to the USA and spending $100,000+ may help. For most people, that's just not an option. If you want to know if there are newer or better immunotherapies, ask that instead.

Comment: @KateGregory you mean to ask it on this site? Or in other hospitals?  Do you think there is the possibility of sharing her medical record with specialists elsewhere and getting feedback?

Comment: You can ask here. Something like "immunotherapy options are moving fast. Is X the latest thing for melanoma or is there something else in trials now?" That's not asking for a diagnosis or personal advice, but it will let you know whether there even is something else you could be trying to pursue. And yes, you could also ask your aunt's doctor whether she is showing a response (partial or complete) and whether there are other options.

Answer (score 3):

If you're searching for treatments that are not currently main stream, you need to look on https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=melanoma+and+spain&Search=Search to see if there's a trial in your city or any other local to you.

However, most oncologists will be aware of these trials.  If you're prepared to travel, and can afford treatment in the USA or other countries, then you can look worldwide for experimental treatments.